# 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Please refer my following code. I have updated all my latest code in `styles.xml` too. `AppCompatActivity` is extended and support libraries are used. Please guide me , thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.preciset3.tuesday;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 ListView listView;
    ActionBar actionBar;
     ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
//        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navbar);
        android.widget.ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     ActionBar  actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
//        (this).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      //  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //    actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,)

    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using a `NoActionBar` theme, you have to set a `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar` before you call `getSupportActionBar()`. If you're not using a `Toolbar`, then don't use a `NoActionBar` theme.

Comment: What style theme you are using?

Comment: Mike M.... Can you please guide me to add the toolbar into mu ActionBar with java coding...Thanks in advance...

Comment: @DineshkumarV Please see the answer for `Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AppCompatActivity` and `getSupportActionBar()`, so i think u check your `styles.xml` and see that u parent with `AppCompat` Theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: My styles.xml is right here,        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps for adding the toolbar as you asked in your comment for the steps. First change the style

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/camera</item>

    </style>
```

Then create the toolbar layout.

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_toolbar"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then in your `Activity` layout

**acitivyt_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And then in your `MainActivity`

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ImageView iv_profilePic, ivEditImage;
    private EditText etName, etEmail, etPhoneNumber;
    private ImageChooserManager imageChooserManager;
    private String filePath = "";
    private int chooserType;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_myaccount);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this

```
package com.example.preciset3.tuesday;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView listView;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navbar);
        android.widget.ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

       assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

}
```